# Allocating Dynamic Memory to PlayerID

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, dynamic-memory-allocation

For hours now I've been trying to work out to how I can assign dynamic memory to a certain playerid, when they join a server, and destroy it when they leave.

I've tried numerous things, I've tried making an array of pointers... which would allow me to access the information with the player ID using the pointer and array position:

```
int *pInfo[MAX_PLAYERS]; // Global

//Function Local
CPlayers p;
pInfo[playerid] = p;
```

Which doesn't work, it tells me it cannot convert the class initialisation to a memory pointer.

I tried the same thing, with this line instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<CPlayers> pInfo[playerid];
```

However it needs a constant expression where playerid is, this means I cannot do this unless I know what the player ID is and enter it directly... which is impossible as I won't know until they client tries to connect.

Does anyone have a solution that will allow me to make memory dynamically, and have this memory accessible via the playerid. Or some other fashion, that me indefinitely use that clients information in game.

As I have ran out of ideas... I can't find anything online. I'm new as well so there may be functions I've over looked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MAP container to do that. The ideia is that you have 2 values. The first one is the playerID and the second one, a dynamic memory reference, which contains its properties. Following is a simple example to prove the concept.

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> pinfo;

    // Inserting some elements.
    pinfo.emplace(1, std::unique_ptr<int>(new int{3}));
    pinfo.emplace(800, std::unique_ptr<int>(new int{700}));

    for (auto& i: pinfo)
        std::cout << "Player " << i.first << ", value " << *i.second.get() << std::endl;

    // Deleting. Note that, due unique_ptr, the memory is deallocated automatically
    pinfo.erase(1);

    std::cout << "Player 1: deleted" << std::endl;
    for (auto& i: pinfo)
        std::cout << "Player " << i.first << ", value " << *i.second.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran your test code. It ran perfectly, allocated and de-allocated the memory like a dream :D. Thanks for your reply, you've been a great help. Now I can get back to learning again :).